# Set variables extracting values to store from list of dicts

Tags: ansible

I need to set variables whose names must be `my_dict` keys and the values to store into the variables must be the value of `stdout` in the `my_list` element that has the item `value1`, which is also the value of `key1` inside `my_dict`.

```yaml
---
- name: Vars from dict

  tasks:
  - name: Get vars from dict

    my_dict:
      key1: "value1"
      key2: "value2"

# list of dicts
    my_list: [ { item: "value1", stdout: "1"}, { item: "value2", stdout: "2" } ]

# I'm setting variables here
# variable key1 must be set to the value of "stdout" key belonging to the dict whose "item" key contains "value1" 
# (i.e. "1" in this case)

  - set_fact:
      key1: "1"
      key2: "2"
```

I hope the code example clarifies a bit.

How is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

To get familiar with the data structure and a better understanding how to access certain parts of it, you may have a look into the following debug example.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    my_list: [ { item: "value1", stdout: "1"}, { item: "value2", stdout: "2" } ]

  tasks:

  - name: Show var
    debug:
      var: my_list

  - name: Show values
    debug:
      msg:
      - "{{ item }}"
      - "{{ item.stdout }}"
    loop: "{{ my_list }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: true
      label: "{{ ansible_loop.index0 }}"
```

Resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show var] *************
ok: [localhost] =>
  my_list:
  - item: value1
    stdout: '1'
  - item: value2
    stdout: '2'

TASK [Show values] ***********
ok: [localhost] => (item=0) =>
  msg:
  - item: value1
    stdout: '1'
  - '1'
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) =>
  msg:
  - item: value2
    stdout: '2'
  - '2'
```

**Further Readings**

- [Data manipulation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html)
- [Extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables)